# connecting 2 VLANs on same switch will cause loop?

Tags: networking, switch, loopback

I was wondering if I connect 2 VLANs on the same switch would cause a loop ?

If yes, why does it ? because every 4 ports are in other vlan

I've added a picture to demonstrate

[image]

Comment: Why? Do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound At my work, people there mess with the SWITCH and connect like this, so I wanted to know if this causes problems in the network or if it actually does not cause any problems because each VLAN is separate, although I think yes because BROADCAST reaches all the ports and then there is a LOOP , im wronge? –

Comment: Think like this: you are connecting two different switches of two different networks with a cable. Why would this lead to a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bridging two VLANs like that doesn't create a loop - assuming ports 3 and 6 are assigned the shown VLAN as untagged/native.

There's a loop when frames can run in a circle. E.g. if port 6 was running VLAN 1 untagged and VLAN 2 tagged, then that would create a loop on VLAN 1.

However, bridging those VLANs essentially creates a single VLAN = L2 segment - so there's no point in configuring two VLANs.

Also, if the switch is configured for RSTP or MSTP (single instance), the two ports connected to each other are detected as redundant and the link will be blocked.

> At my work, people there mess with the SWITCH and connect like this

You need a policy forbidding unqualified personnel to mess with the cabling. If you need a technical solution you should check out port-based NAC, e.g. 802.1X.

Comment: when i have enable the loop detection on the switch its saying that port 6 is loop so Bridging two VLANs like that does create a loop..i was thinking that no..:)

Comment: There's no real loop in your diagram, but loop protection may detect two ports connected to each other anyway, depending on (proprietary) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When a port belongs to two or more VLANs of the same type, they remain as separate broadcast domains and cannot receive traffic from each other without routing.
[image]

[https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/YA-YB/15-18/5998-8157_yayb_2530_atmg/content/ch01s02.html#:~:text=When%20a%20port%20belongs%20to,receive%20traffic%20from%20each%20other](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/YA-YB/15-18/5998-8157_yayb_2530_atmg/content/ch01s02.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20port%20belongs%20to,receive%20traffic%20from%20each%20other)

Comment: https://imgur.com/KauStGb , loop?

Comment: creating a cable connection between two VLANs on a switch can potentially lead to a loop in the network. To prevent loops, it's essential to implement proper Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) configurations on the switch. STP helps identify and block redundant paths in the network, preventing loops from forming

Comment: how it can lead to a loops ? i was thinking that vlan its like a different wall from other vlans. data from vlan 1 cant go to vlan2 . or there are packets that do ?